WPF ScrollViewer-Template prevents Textbox from Scrolling thru with mouse wheel or following cursor
I created a ScrollViewer Template in WPF to make my scroll bars look more simplistic.
The only problem is apparently this template prevents my TextBox from scrolling thru by mouse wheel.
So I have a AcceptReturn (Multiline) TextBox in my Window with some lines of text (enough to make the scroll bar appear) but I cant scroll thru with my mouse wheel. Also The TextBox wont follow the cursor if I write new lines.
I testet it by commenting/removing the template and everything works fine but if I use the template it stops working again!
Here is my template:
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Color x:Key="ScrollBarFgOnColor">#A000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ScrollBarFgColor">#7000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ScrollBarBgColor">#01ffffff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ScrollBarFgOffColor">#3000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ScrollBarBgOffColor">#2fff</Color>

    <sys:Double x:Key="ScrollBarBarWidth">7</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="ScrollBarBtnWidth">0</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="ScrollBarMargin">1</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="ScrollBarCornerRad">0</sys:Double>
    
    <!-- ####################################################### -->

    <Thickness x:Key="ScrollBarBtnMarginT"
               Top="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"
               Left="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"
               Right="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"
               Bottom="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"/>

    <Thickness x:Key="ScrollBarBarMargin"
               Top="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"
               Left="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"
               Right="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"
               Bottom="{StaticResource ScrollBarMargin}"/>

    <CornerRadius x:Key="ScrollBarThumbCRad"
                  TopLeft="{StaticResource ScrollBarCornerRad}"
                  TopRight="{StaticResource ScrollBarCornerRad}"
                  BottomRight="{StaticResource ScrollBarCornerRad}"
                  BottomLeft="{StaticResource ScrollBarCornerRad}"/>

    <!--ScrollViewer Start #####################################################################-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource ScrollBarFgColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarForegroundBrushPressed" Color="{StaticResource ScrollBarFgOnColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource ScrollBarBgColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarDisabledForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource ScrollBarFgOffColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarDisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource ScrollBarBgOffColor}" />

    <!-- SrollViewer ScrollBar Repeat Buttons (at each end) -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border
                            x:Name="Border"
                            Margin="0"
                            CornerRadius="0"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                            BorderThickness="0">
                        <Path
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBarForegroundBrush}"
                                Data="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnMarginT}" Stretch="Fill" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                    Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarForegroundBrushPressed}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- SrollViewer ScrollBar Repeat Buttons (The part in the middle, 
             not the thumb the long area between the buttons ) -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" />
                    <!--BeforAndAfterBG-->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- ScrollViewer ScrollBar Thumb, that part that can be dragged
            up/down or left/right Buttons -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border
                            x:Name="Border"
                            CornerRadius="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumbCRad}"
                            Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarForegroundBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                            BorderThickness="0" Margin="{StaticResource ScrollBarBarMargin}" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                    Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarForegroundBrushPressed}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
            TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border
                    Grid.RowSpan="3"
                    Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarBackgroundBrush}" />
            <RepeatButton
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                    Height="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"
                    Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"
                    Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
            <Track
                    x:Name="PART_Track"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsDirectionReversed="true">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton
                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                            Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb
                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
                            Margin="0"
                            Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarForegroundBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton
                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                            Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                    Height="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"
                    Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand"
                    Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- HorizontalScrollBar Template using the previously created Templates -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar"
            TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarBackgroundBrush}" />
            <RepeatButton
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                    Width="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"
                    Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"
                    Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
            <Track
                    x:Name="PART_Track"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton
                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                            Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb
                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
                            Margin="-4,5"
                            Background="{StaticResource ScrollBarForegroundBrush}"
                            BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton
                            Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                            Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                    Width="{StaticResource ScrollBarBtnWidth}"
                    Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"
                    Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <!-- Style for overall  ScrollBar -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarBarWidth}" />
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarBarWidth}"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <!-- Style for overall  ScrollViewer -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ScrollContentPresenter/>

                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                   Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollBarBackgroundBrush}" Grid.Row="1"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!--ScrollViewer End #######################################################################-->
</ResourceDictionary>

Here is my TextBox
        <TextBox x:Name="ContentTxb" Width="200" Height="200"
                 IsReadOnly="True" Cursor="Arrow"
                 TextChanged="ContentTxb_TextChanged"
                 BorderThickness="0" Margin="10 15 10 10" Padding="0"
                 ContextMenu="{Binding ElementName=Win, Path=ContextMenu}"
                 Background="{StaticResource BgBru}" Foreground="{StaticResource FgBru}"
                 FontFamily="DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font" FontSize="12"
                 AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" AutoWordSelection="False"
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30" UndoLimit="1000"
                 UseLayoutRounding="True"
                 SelectionOpacity=".5">
        </TextBox>


It doesn't reproduce. A TextBox inside this ScrollViewer is scrollable with mouse wheel.

To be clear the TextBox is not inside a scroll viewer. The template affects the nativ ScrollViewer inside of the TextBox. And for changing the look that is correct, just not function wise.

So you intentionally apply this Template to the ScrollViewer inside TextBox without knowing possible side-effects?
